# Read and write files in Qt C++

Tags: c++, file, qt

I'm new to the programming in Qt.

I'm doing a program consisting of a main screen and 3 windows, is based on driving a truck radio controlled by the parallel port.

My problem is that in the second window, I enter certain values, and stored in a txt file (I checked and stored properly).  The problem is that when I go to the third window, which is designed to read and print the data generated file, do not appear, but until I leave and get back into the program.

Although after saving the data, I close the file and then I open it to read it, it's like not close at that time, but only when I exit the program.

Below attached program files.

[Link!](http://www.mediafire.com/file/58z6f856oj91orp/proyecto.rar)

Thank you very much and sorry for my english!

Note: Do not forget to enter with user permission to run the program (work in Ubuntu), as it handles PC ports.

Comment: Mhhhh... Can you try to force the file to flush before close?

Comment: close() flushes file automatically, there is no need to call both.

Comment: My guess is that all your windows are created when the application starts and your third window immediately reads the file. The second windows writes to the file sometimes later. Have you run the application in the debugger and checked that writing and reading happens in the order you think it happens?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! 
Roku : How I can do to make the third window is updated after saving the file?

Comment: Well, there are many ways. If you are creating all the windows when the application starts, you could use Qt's signal and slot mechanism. Make a fileChanged signal to the second window and an onFileChanged slot to the third window. And then connect the signal to the slot. When the second window has changed the file, it emits the fileChanged signal. The third window's slot is called and it can read the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a very clear answer, I will try what you say!

Comment: @Roku Excuse me, but can not find how to do what you say, I understand the concept but do not know how to do it :(
If you tell me how to make you appreciate what we have to deliver this project in a few days, is for college.
I just need that part and this finished! Thanks!

Comment: .h section:
`Class WindowA : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
signals:
  void fileChanged(void);

}

Class WindowB : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

slots:
  void onFileChanged(void);

}`

.cpp section:
When creating object of type `WindowA`, emit signal `fileChanged()` when file is changed. And when creating object of type `WindowB`, connect signal `fileChanged()` to your slot `onFileChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-application.html) qt example:

```
bool MainWindow::saveFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) 
    {
            QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Application"),
                          tr("Cannot write file %1:\n%2.")
                          .arg(fileName)
                          .arg(file.errorString()));
        return false;
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
#endif
out << textEdit->toPlainText();
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
#endif

    setCurrentFile(fileName);
    statusBar()->showMessage(tr("File saved"), 2000);
    return true;
}
```

you could define this and define a slot that ask to the user a file name(QFileDialog is the quickest way), if user accept (does not cancel save data execution) you call this method with user file name. You can drop some stuff, i.e. statusBar()->showMessage(); if you don't have a status bar and so on...